# Grabbing & displaying the current time

Tags: python, datetime

I'm very new to python and trying to build a simple web app in pieces.

I'm using the datetime library for the first time so please be patient with me.

All I'm trying to do is to get and display the current time and date so that I can cross-reference it with a target time & date later.

I'm getting some colossal errors. Any help is appreciated. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here to display the time formatted the way I want.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "4:21 PM 1.24.2011"
format = "%I.%M %p %m %d, %Y"
my_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)

print(my_date.strftime(format))
```

Comment: ...and what errors are you getting, exactly?

Comment: So I simplified the program to this and it's working fine. Does this make sense: import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print(now.strftime("%I.%M %p %m %d, %Y"))

Answer (score 3):

The format of the date_string doesn't match the format you're trying to parse it with. The following format string should allow you to parse the date.

```
 format = "%I:%M %p %m.%d.%Y"
```

And afterwards, if you want to print it using the other format

```
print(my_date.strftime("%I.%M %p %m %d, %Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong format string. Try to replace it with `"%I:%M %p %m.%d.%Y"`.

[Here's](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) documentation how to use `datetime` class properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `format`. You need to make the format match `date_string`. So try this:

```
format = "%I:%M %p %m.%d.%Y"
```

That should do the trick

Also, it might be of interest to you to take a look at `time.asctime`